# Change values in two columns of a matrix depending on their original values

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `a`,

```
a=[0  0  0  0  1
   0  0  0  1  0
   0  0  1 -1 -1
   0  1  0 -1 -1
   1 -1 -1 -1 -1];
```

I want to create new matrix `b` from matrix `a`, according to the values in columns 2 and 3.

- If the second and third columns are `0 0` (as in case of the first two rows) then I want to change those values to `10 9`.
- If the second and third column are `0 1` (as in the case of the third row) then I want to change those values to `12 9`.

So the output would be

```
b=[0 10  9  0  1
   0 10  9  1  0
   0 12  9 -1 -1
   0  1  0 -1 -1
   1 -1 -1 -1 -1];
```

Comment: Wow, before the edit I was having a seizure, but after the edit I can actually understand this now!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want using logical indexing. For example, the first one can be realised as follows:

```
idx = a(:, 2) == 0 & a(:, 3) == 0;
a(idx, 2) = 10;
a(idx, 3) = 9;
```

I think you should be able to do the second one yourself.

It may be interesting to have a look at the [Getting Started](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) tutorial.